# DDD - Contacting an invitation

Tags: domain-driven-design

The domain I am working with is a membership system.  I have a domain concept called an Enrollment Invitation Period, during which users can invite others to sign up for membership.  The Enrollment Invitation Period can be open/closed and holds Invitations.  Invitations are a name and email address.

I have a requirement: When an Enrollment Invitation Period is open, it should contact any uncontacted invitations.  In my mind, this is something the Enrollment Invitation Period class should be responsible for.  It has access to all of the information required to satisfy this business need.

Next, I have an Email Service.  It is responsible for getting templates, building and sending emails.  It is Infrastructure.

So my question.  How should the Enrollment Invitation Period domain object interact with the Email Service.

A) Inject the service (through abstraction) into the contact function?  Does this tie the domain to closely to the infrastructure?

```
var period = repo.Get(id);
period.ContactInvitations(emailService);
```

B) Write a domain service that queries the invitation period for information?

```
(In Service)
var period = repo.Get(id);
if (period.IsOpen)
{
   var unconcacted = period.GetUncontactedInvitations();
   foreach(var i in uncontacted)
   {
        var email = BuildEmailFromInvitaion(i);
        emailService.Send(email);
   }
}
```

From my gut, A seems better.  B doesn't seem to reflect the language of 'invitation periods contact invitees'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) Inject the service (through abstraction) into the contact function? Does this tie the domain to closely to the infrastructure?

This, with the understanding that the abstraction that you pass in is the *domain service*.

```
var period = repo.Get(id);
period.ContactInvitations(emailService);
```

This spelling here is very good, provided that `emailService` is a domain service; the email capabilities that it exposes should be expressed in the language of the domain model.

In this pattern, the domain service is acting as an adapter that accepts domain concepts as arguments, and passes them along to the email infrastructure.

> Does this tie the domain to closely to the infrastructure?

No, because the domain service acts as a seam between the model and the infrastructure -- you can easily replace the instance of the domain service that talks to the email infrastructure with an instance that talks to a test double.

> From my gut, A seems better. B doesn't seem to reflect the language of 'invitation periods contact invitees'.

B violates [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).  That's not necessarily wrong (engineering is tradeoffs) but other things being equal that wouldn't be my first choice.

> That service would be responsible for converting the Invitation into an email and sending that message to the infrastrcture email service. It would also mark the Invitation as sent. Is that right?

Maybe - the aggregate is still responsible for tracking its own state; the domain service is just handling the email part; this domain service really shouldn't know anything about the internals of your model.

```
Period::ContactInvitations(emailService) {
    for(invitation : uncontacted) {
        if (emailService.contact(...)) {
            this.onContacted(invitation);
        }
    }
}
```

Pseudo code to give you the basic idea -- you'll want to be thinking about failure modes and so on.

Comment: Ok.  Let me see if I understand this then.  I could create a domain service called InvitationSender which would accept the domain object Invitation.  That service would be responsible for converting the Invitation into an email and sending that message to the infrastrcture email service.  It would also mark the Invitation as sent.  Is that right?